# How to effectively display data in a collectionview from two different Firebase references in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to display data in a CollectionView from two different Firebase references.

**Instead of writing two separate queries and combining both snapshots into one, What is the most efficient way?**

A `user` can receive both a `compliment` and an `invite` from other users.

I need to fetch both a list of all `users` that have sent either an `invite` or `compliment`, combine into the same array/dictionary and load a `CollectionView`.

The following database structure is built when either a `compliment` or `invite` is sent.

[image]

**Is there a more efficient way where I can combine the two query references and merging them both?**

A query for `compliments`

```
ref = REF_USERS_COMPLIMENTS.child(forId).child(currentUid).observe(.childAdded , with: { (snapshot) in...
```

A query for `invites`

```
ref = REF_USERS_INVITES.child(forId).child(currentUid).observe(.childAdded , with: { (snapshot) in...
```